# Parity: How to view connected Peers alternative to 'admin' keyword?

Tags: parity

As we know we cannot use `admin`, which works on `geth`, on `Parity`.

For example I want to retrieve information such as `enode-id`, ip-address, used port of each connected peer.

`parity_netPeers` (https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_netpeers) returns some information without newline, it become difficult see detect the peers connected.

`curl --data '{"method":"parity_netPeers","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545`

**Example:**

Here there is actually 2 connected peers but it returns many more information.

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"active":2,"connected":2,"max":25,"peers":[{"caps":[],"id":"575bbc154d3c37c35d5f91a42813641fef4389bc288c0e50cf2ab1cbbde014287b93d3748336ff02c99a11e7d58ab54868933c7a9804c36a071078cb9a586ca8","name":"","network":{"localAddress":"77.23.7.15:39741","remoteAddress":"Handshake"},"protocols":{"eth":null,"les":null}},{"caps":["eth/63","eth/62"],"id":"4d331051d8fb471c87a9351b36ffb72bf445a9337727d229e03c668f99897264bf11e1b897b1561f5889825e2211b06858139fa469fdf73c64d43a567ea72479","name":"Geth/v1.5.9-stable-a07539fb/linux/go1.7.1","network":{"localAddress":"77.13.17.145:35507","remoteAddress":"13.40.17.95:3000"},"protocols":{"eth":{"difficulty":null,"head":"3060e08b5cd0b90adb3c464342f6df13482361e8ef09724d7525cae48abbaf59","version":63},"les":null}},{"caps":[],"id":"13d6cc66f445072d2e389c5d47d1557543ec9f96237576a38072a5b76b67ba445050641219e1f42c1443a7287fab6cb3f4c078fa886520cbf3577ac23f5e0cad","name":"","network":{"localAddress":"77.13.17.15:44079","remoteAddress":"Handshake"},"protocols":{"eth":null,"les":null}},{"caps":[],"id":null,"name":"","network":{"lo`
...`

Comment: In the Wallet on the Status tab :)

Comment: How? Which wallet? On parity’s gui page? @5chdn

Comment: Yes, on the status tab.

Comment: Well I am not a gui person. Parity works on a node that I access via ssh. It does not have any GUI :( @5chdn.

Comment: If you are not a gui person, JSON must be perfect for you :)

Comment: parity_netPeers returns too many information, I got lost which one is which. It says 2 peers are connected but it returns 25 peer information in total. @5chdn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65951/discussion-between-5chdn-and-avatar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), a command-line JSON processor. It's like `sed` for JSON.

Run this

```
curl -s --data '{"method":"parity_netPeers","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545 \
| jq '.result.peers[] | .id, .network'
```

Add the name of the key preceded by a comma after `.network` and before the single quote to add anything else to the output.

Answer (score -3):

You can use **net.peerCount** at geth console to get the count of peers currently there in the network.
**admin.peers** is another way by which you can get detailed information about the peers in the network.

Comment: I need enode information of the peers. admin.peers does not work at Parity. `> admin.peers
ReferenceError: 'admin' is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1` @Anchit Seth